# How to Pass Object property value as data in Laravel component?

Tags: php, laravel, components

here is my Component markup input.blade.php

```
<div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <label for="{{$name}}"> {{$label}}
            @if($required) </label><span class="text-danger pl-1">*</span> @endif
        <input 
            class="form-control" 
            onkeyup="document.getElementById('account_holder_name').value = this.value" 
            value="{{ old($name) ?? $value }}" 
            name="{{$name}}" 
            type="text" id="{{$name}}" 
            aria-required="{{$required}}" 
            required="{{$required}}">
    </div>
    @error("{{$name}}")
        <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
    @enderror
</div>
```

I want to pass `:value = $supplier->name` instead of below I passed

```
 @php $name = $supplier->name @endphp
 <x-forms.input type='text' name='name' label='Name' :value=$name required=true />
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```php
<x-forms.input type="text" name="name" label="Name" value="{{$supplier->name}}" required="true" />
```

Comment: Ahh I've got the problem! Change to this: `:value="'{{$supplier->name}}'"` or to this: `value="{{$supplier->name}}"`. This happen because your variable is type of string and `:value` expects anything else but string!

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to create a collection then convert  toJson().  once in the component jason_decode to turn back into an object then cycle thru normally.